# Receive memory address call lambda

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 columns in pandas, I need to compare row by row after assiging the first row first column df.a to first row second column df.as1. Then going down the rows, need to compare the current row df.a with the previous row df.as1 using the following function to become the current row df.as1. I use lambda to call function, but receive the memory address but no data.

My code as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

list = [1,1,0,1,-1,0,1,1,-1,-1,-1, 0, -1, 1, 0, 1]
df = pd.DataFrame(list, columns=['a'])

def ckd_count(x):
    df.loc[0,'as1']= df.loc[0,'a']
    if (((df.a + df.as1.shift(1)) >= 1)| ((df.a + df.as1.shift(1)) <= -1) |
        ((df['a'] == 0) & (df.as1.shift(1) == 1)) |((df['a'] == 0) & (df.as1.shift(1) == -1))):
        return df.as1.shift(1)
    elif (((df['a'] == 1) & (df.as1.shift(1) == 0)) |((df['a'] == -1) & (df.as1.shift(1) == 0))):
         return df['a']
    elif (((df['a'] == 0) & (df.as1.shift(1) == 0)) |((df['a'] == 1) & (df.as1.shift(1) == -1))):
        return 0

df.as1 = df['a'].apply(lambda x: ckd_count,)
```

I get the result as follows:

```
df.as1
0     <function ckd_count at 0x0000010EDE57DC10>
1     <function ckd_count at 0x0000010EDE57DC10>
2     <function ckd_count at 0x0000010EDE57DC10>
3     <function ckd_count at 0x0000010EDE57DC10>
4     <function ckd_count at 0x0000010EDE57DC10>
5     <function ckd_count at 0x0000010EDE57DC10>
6     <function ckd_count at 0x0000010EDE57DC10>
7     <function ckd_count at 0x0000010EDE57DC10>
8     <function ckd_count at 0x0000010EDE57DC10>
9     <function ckd_count at 0x0000010EDE57DC10>
10    <function ckd_count at 0x0000010EDE57DC10>
11    <function ckd_count at 0x0000010EDE57DC10>
12    <function ckd_count at 0x0000010EDE57DC10>
13    <function ckd_count at 0x0000010EDE57DC10>
14    <function ckd_count at 0x0000010EDE57DC10>
15    <function ckd_count at 0x0000010EDE57DC10>
Name: as1, dtype: object
```

Any suggestion , please let me know.

Comment: You haven't called the function

Comment: Either do `.apply(lambda x: ckd_count(x))` or just `.apply(ckd_count)`

Comment: I try to use apply(lambda x: ckd_count(x)).  I got "The truth value of a Series is ambiguous..." error. Then I try to use np.equal to compare 2 columns, still got the same error. Any idea why.